# Pase json in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse json in JavaScript

```
var str = '{"id-1": "www.er.co.uk","id-2": "www.wer.co.uk","id-3": "wer.wer.com","id-4": "www.wwaer.co.uk"}';

var divWebsite = JSON.parse(str);
```

i am getting error ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05dn7mpa/4/))

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

While at the same time my json is valid as you can see here http://jsonlint.com/ (sorry you will need to copy and past json)

Comment: You are trying to parse a Javascript object, not JSON, JSON is a string

Comment: i am trying to crate jsvascript object fom json

Comment: *"i am trying to crate jsvascript object fom json"* But you **already** have a JavaScript object. `{"foo": 42}` is a JavaScript object. `'{"foo": 42}'` is a string containing JSON. JSON is a **textual, language-independent** data format, like YAML or XML.

Comment: @Hacketo is right, it is not a JSON string

Comment: You are trying to create a javascript object from a javascript object in your code.

Comment: The code in your updated example doesn't throw the error you claim it does. It works as expected.

Comment: Definitely spend some time to learn and understand the difference between a JavaScript object and JSON. They both look similar, but they are two completely different things.

Comment: thanks... javascript is really confusing

Comment: While JSON was inspired by JavaScript it actually has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not JSON. You can see the difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/05dn7mpa/2/

So if you have an string with a json you can parse it. If you've got the propper vanilla object it's parsed !

```
  var divWebsite = JSON.parse('{    "id-1": "www.er.co.uk",    "id-2": "www.wer.co.uk",    "id-3": "wer.wer.com",    "id-4": "www.wwaer.co.uk"}');
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to pass a string to JSON.parse

HTML

```
<div id="parsed"></div>
```

JS

```
  var divWebsite = JSON.parse('{"id-1": "www.er.co.uk","id-2": "www.wer.co.uk","id-3": "wer.wer.com","id-4": "www.wwaer.co.uk"}');

  document.getElementById('parsed').innerHTML = divWebsite['id-1'];
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/05dn7mpa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

What you pass to `JSON.parse()` is not a string, that's why. You pass an object. In a typical scenario you want `JSON.parse` to return that object. What you should pass is a string.

If you want to get a json string out of that object use `JSON.stringify()`